# Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "log" does not exist for laravel project in xampp

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, xampp

I try to clone the Laravel project stored in Nginx to another server with Xampp.
Both running in Window 10.
After the cloning, it was unable to start the project and prompt out the following message and I am not sure what can I do... Any suggestions or advice?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "log" does not exist in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:734
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(734): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(849): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
#4 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(804): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(774): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Exceptions\...', Array)
#7 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Exceptions\...', Array)
#8 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Exceptions\...', Array)
#9 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(731): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#10 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#11 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\Cont...', Array)
#12 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1178): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\Cont...')
#13 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(279): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('Illuminate\Cont...')
#14 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(105): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#15 C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 {main} thrown in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\ssg_website\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 734
```

Comment: Where are you using it?

Comment: Can you please run this command  `composer install` and then check again?

Answer (score -1):

This problem is settled by changing the composer.json file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).